# I need Oracle query to get sales of a product only if its greater than its previous month

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum, window-functions

Example:

```
PROD_ID SALES DATE
1       400   12-APR-2020
1       300   20-apr-2020
2       300   23-MAY-2020
2       300   20-may-2020
```

and result should be

```
1 700
```

`prod id` should be compared between May and April sales and display one which is max between two months.

Comment: Something's wrong with sample data. How can we compare PROD_ID = 1 (or 2, the same thing) between April and May if both of its dates are in April?

Answer (score 1):

Group by month and then find the first row.

```sql
SELECT prod_id,
       SUM( SALES ) AS total_sales
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY prod_id, TRUNC( "DATE", 'MM' )
ORDER BY total_sales DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT PROD_ID,
       total_sales
FROM   (
  SELECT prod_id,
         SUM( SALES ) AS total_sales,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY SUM( SALES ) DESC ) AS rnk
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY prod_id, TRUNC( "DATE", 'MM' )
)
WHERE  rnk = 1
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( PROD_ID, SALES, "DATE" ) AS
SELECT 1, 400, DATE '2020-04-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 300, DATE '2020-04-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 300, DATE '2020-05-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 300, DATE '2020-05-20' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> ```
> PROD_ID | TOTAL_SALES
> ------: | ----------:
>       1 |         700
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8b86c0a26979f63f3d1a2bb67cdd5c61)*

Answer (score 1):

> I need Oracle query to get sales of a product only if its greater than its previous month

If your data spreads over more than 2 months, then I would recommend aggregation and `lag()`:

```
select *
from (
    select
        prod_id,
        trunc(sales_date, 'mm') sales_month,
        sum(sales) total_sales,
        lag(sum(sales)) over(partition by prod_id order by trunc(sales_date, 'mm')) lag_total_sales
    from mytable 
    group by prod_id, trunc(sales_date, 'mm')
) t
where total_sales > lag_total_sales
```

The subquery computes the total sales per product and per month, and uses `lag()` to retrieve the total sales of the previous month. Then, the outer query filters on product/month tuples whose monthly sales is greater than on last month.

You might want to define precisely how the first sales month of a product should be handled. The above query will filter it out (since there is no "previous" month). If you want to retain it in the resultset, you can change the `where` clause to:

```
where lag_total_sales is null or total_sales > lag_total_sales
```